# Why a binding's StringFormat didn't use a current culture?

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7, xaml

My current culture is ru-RU. I need it to format decimal to currency string.

```
decimal n = 111.22M;

n.ToString("C") will return "111,22р."
```

but when I try to use StringFormat field of a binding I get a "$111.22" result

```
<TextBlock Text={Binding Number, StringFormat=C} />
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

By default, WPF will use English as the culture for binding `StringFormat` processing, not the thread's current culture.

You can override this by adding the following in the application's startup code:

```
FrameworkElement.LanguageProperty.OverrideMetadata(typeof(FrameworkElement),
    new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(      XmlLanguage.GetLanguage(CultureInfo.CurrentCulture.IetfLanguageTag)));
```

For details, see Josh Smith's article on [Creating an Internationalized Wizard](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/31837/Creating-an-Internationalized-Wizard-in-WPF).

Comment: This workaround can't be applied because Windows Phone does not support `OverrideMetadata` method.

Comment: As Alex said, this does not work on Windows Phone. You can however utilize something like this:
System.Threading.Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture = System.Globalization.CultureInfo.CurrentCulture;

Comment: Linked article is dead